# Hibernate setMaxResult on parent limit child collection too

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a parent entity with a @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) child collection.

I need to load only first record i found of Parent entity, so i load it using this criteria:

```
session.createCriteria(Parent.class).setMaxResult(1).uniqueResult();
```

Work fine, but the limit is applied to child collection too, and this is very bad.

How can i get only first record of parent, but all record of its child?

Thanks

Comment: I just ran into this. This is wierd.

Answer (score 3):

Just mark the collection of children as `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`, don't fetch it in the query and initialize the collection after the query if necessary:

```
Parent p = (Parent) session.createCriteria(Parent.class).setMaxResult(1).uniqueResult();
// if necessary:
Hibernate.initialize(p.getChildren());
```

If you really want to keep the association as eager fetched (which is a bad idea, IMO), then only load the ID of the parent in the query, and then get the parent:

```
Long parentId = (Long) session.createCriteria(Parent.class)
                              .setProjection(Projections.id())
                              .setMaxResult(1)
                              .uniqueResult();
Parent p = session.get(Parent.class, parentId);
```

Comment: any better way to achieve this? I'm facing it now