# Hibernate, collection fetch eager returns only one tuple whent criteria setMaxResults(1) is used

Tags: sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm

```
public static final class EntityA {

        @Id
        Long id;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
        Set<EntityB> set = new HashSet<>();
}

public static final class EntityB {
        @Id
        Long id;

        String name;
}
```

However, when I query the EntityA using hibernate criterias, and do `criteria.setMaxResults( 1 );`

The **set** only returns one tuple, even if it contains many more.

When I disregard the `setMaxResults(1)` I do get everything in the collection and my instance of EntityA.

Also, when I use `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` I do get all, despite having setMaxResults(1);

Also, when I use `setFetchSize(1)` it also returns all, if not `setMaxResults(1)` but I do believe one should be using setMaxResutls to limit the returned list on EntityA.

Is this a bug?

SUBSELECT is not as performant as JOIN why I'd like to understand why this is happening.

The criteria is being used on EntityA and max result on that.

Comment: Related but no satisfying answer, explaining why there is a limit on the eagerly fetched collection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430965/hibernate-setmaxresult-on-parent-limit-child-collection-too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setMaxResults` limits the number of **rows**, not the amount of entity instances that you wanna get (see [section *Pagination*](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing)).

The EntityA's **set**, by default and based on the entity model you posted, is fetched using a *join* with the entityA instance. So set MaxResults to 1 is limiting to retrieve just one row which means just the instance entityA and the one assocciated.

With `FetchMode.SELECT`, the **set** is retrieved by a select query different from the one that retrieves entityA.

I suggest you take a look at [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins) and the section about [performance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching) of the Hibernate Manual to see the options you have and what the fetch strategies do (also [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/) is a by-example explanation)